# Solr returning Facets that are not on the Results

Tags: solr, facet

I'm getting the same facets (basically the full list of all the values that exist on any item for that property) for every search. I'm faceting on a multilist field of Traits, and no matter how i limit my search, I always get ALL the existing Traits, not just the Traits that are actually on those results. In fact, even when I modify my search such that I get NO resutls, I still get every Trait. Why is it giving me facets that aren't on the results?

```
using (var searchContext = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentTypeSearchResultItem>();
    var contentType = Constants.Taxonomy.Product;

    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.ContentType.Contains(contentType));
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.TemplateId.Guid == templateId);

    var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<ContentTypeSearchResultItem>().Filter(predicate);
    query = query
        .FacetOn(x => x.Traits)
            
    var results = query.GetResults();

    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Results:", this);

    var items = results.Hits.Select(x => x.Document);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info($"{item.Path}", this);
    }

    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Trait Facets:",this);

    var traits = results.Facets.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains("traits"));

    foreach (var trait in traits.Values)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info($"{trait.Name}", this);
    }

    return results.Facets.Categories.ToList();
}
```

I added in some logging, and with the template ID predicate, I actually get zero results but still get the full facet list and get that for every crop type search, here's the logging output:

44312 15:13:01 INFO  Results:
[NO RESULTS LISTED]
44312 15:13:01 INFO  Trait Facets:
44312 15:13:01 INFO  26d3faa9d8e04b5da5a3da77d69a2b51
44312 15:13:01 INFO  54aa71076cf442dfa37c7c5abf3ef0ad
44312 15:13:01 INFO  54c4f97f95c4498e8ca3870687fc6995
44312 15:13:01 INFO  5c3db73e0cd4422abf2e58a431530a4e
44312 15:13:01 INFO  8d4fe44e1523471da89981207895553c
44312 15:13:01 INFO  95f80ed476594995b7878ab4eefa8d98
44312 15:13:01 INFO  a2fc835c202e488991005144af7f2bef
44312 15:13:01 INFO  c91769f140524b8eac5486423cfdb4f3
44312 15:13:01 INFO  d963303d6c284d2db7b1b78a69c38a33

Answer (score 1):

Solr has an optional minimumResultCount that determines how many results are required for that facet value to show up.  It defaults to zero, so if you only want facets that are on the results (e.g. a minimumResultCount of 1), add it to FacetOn:

```
query = query.FacetOn(x => x.Traits, 1)
```